# Download attribute is not working with Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

In my Plain Html file, When i click on CheatSheet link, Chrome Browser navigating to pdf url, instead of forcing me to download. How do i force to download?

```
<a  href="https://web.stanford.edu/group/csp/cs21/htmlcheatsheet.pdf" download>CheatSheet</a>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [html5 href download attribute not working with .pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26290715/html5-href-download-attribute-not-working-with-pdf-file)

Comment: A better dup target: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23872902/chrome-download-attribute-not-working#35290284